# docker-compose force services to create seperate containers even when images are the same

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 services which use the same `image:`, what can i do, to force docker-compose to generate 2 seperate containers?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Full docker-compose:

```
    version: "3.5"
    services:
      database:
        container_name: proj-database
        env_file: ../orm/.env.${PROJ_ENV}
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 5432:5432
        networks:
          - proj
      api:
        image: golang:1.17
        container_name: proj-api
        env_file: ../cryptoModuleAPI/.env.${PROJ_ENV}
        restart: always
        build: ../cryptoModuleAPI/
        links:
          - database:database
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
        volumes:
          - ../cryptoModuleAPI:/proj/api
          - ../orm:/proj/orm
        networks:
          - proj
      admin:
        image: golang:1.17
        container_name: proj-admin
        env_file: ../admin/.env.${PROJ_ENV}
        restart: always
        build: ../admin/
        links:
          - database:database
        ports:
          - 8081:8081
        volumes:
          - ../admin:/proj/admin
          - ../orm:/proj/orm
        networks:
          - proj
    
    networks:
      proj:
        external:
          name: proj
```

I just run with `docker-compose up`

Comment: Isn't that what happens?

Comment: No, both services get hosted on the same image)

Comment: Can you please post your full `docker-compose` and your run commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how the **build** and **image** directives work when used together.

Paraphrasing the docs,

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build

**If you specify image as well as build, then Compose names the built image with the value of the image directive.**

Compose is going to build two images, both named the same thing. Only one will survive. I'm surprised your app spins up at all!

Provide a different name for the image directive of each service, or leave it out entirely.

Comment: (...and, if your Dockerfiles begin `FROM golang:1.17`, you should `docker rmi golang:1.17` since Compose overwrote that image with your application image.)